# How to empty box of asterisks around text perl?

Tags: perl

I'm bringing in text from a file and I need it have a border of asterisks around it. How do I do that?

I've tried this:

```
my $x      = 100;  # width
my $y      = 96;  # number of "hollow" rows

my $solid  = '*' x $x . $/;
my $hollow = '*' . ' ' x ($x-2) . '*' . $/;

print OUT $solid,
    ($hollow) x $y,
      $solid;
```

Comment: `my $x      = 100;  # width                                                                      my $y      = 96;  # number of "hollow" rows

my $solid  = '*' x $x . $/;
my $hollow = '*' . ' ' x ($x-2) . '*' . $/;

print OUT $solid,
    ($hollow) x $y,
     $solid;`

Comment: As you can see, code doesn't show up in comments properly. Please add this to your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can match an asterisk in a regular expression with either `\*` or `[*]`.  So to remove an asterisk just replace it with nothing:

```
$text =~ s/[*]//;
```

To replace asterisks surrounded by optional whitespace at the start of a line:

```
$text =~ s/^\s*[*]+\s*//mg;
```

Similarly at the end:

```
$text =~ s/\s*[*]+\s*$//mg;
```